# How do I get path from url after index.php?

Tags: php, url

I want to get for example ID or any path I set after index.php?

```
"<a href='articles.php?path=". $row ['ID'] ."'>";
```

I get url like http://localhost/cms/articles.php?path=1 I want to put that number 1 or xx number there will be into a variable. How?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read This [GET Method- Tutorials Point](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm) & [GET Method- PHP Net Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) for more info.

```
"<a href='articles.php?path=". $row ['ID'] ."'>";
```

**articles.php**

You can access 'path' through GET.

```
echo $Path=$_GET['path'];
```

Comment: Thanku Bhai @HawasKaPujaari

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that someone clicks on http://localhost/cms/articles.php?path=1, you can get the value of `path` using [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), real example:

1 - First we check if `path` has a value using `!empty` (NOT [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php))
2 - Assign the value of `$_GET['path']` to `$myPath`

**articles.php**

```
if(!empty($_GET['path'])){
$myPath = $_GET['path'];
//now you can use $myPath to, let's say, query a database.
}
```